# Screen video capture of the specific views

Tags: android

Is it possible in Android to capture (record video) from screen only for specific elements (views) of my app's activity?

For example users of the app see (all elements are inflated):

[image]

But screen recorder would record not all elements (for example I don't want to record View 2 - make its visibility "gone" only for screen recorder):

[image]

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html#ScreenCapture - is that API could allow something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great that we can convert views to images and then just use it for a record (blending with other image - frame from camera for example)

```
public Bitmap viewToBitmap(View view) {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        view.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

So I can just convert some RelativeLayout (which contains elements I want to record to a video) to image

Comment: This does not answer your question, as it does not record video.

Comment: @CommonsWare I use javacv ffmpeg for recording, so original android api allows to get images (frames) of what I want see and don't and some libraries (ffmpeg) to record these images in a video. About `ScreenCapture` API - I just asked if it would allow it but question wasn't strongly about this API. So I can say it's pretty easy solution to get what I want without much coding

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible in Android to capture (record video) from screen only for specific elements (views) of my app's activity?

No, sorry.

> is that API could allow something like this?

That will capture everything on the screen: View 1, View 2, the status bar, the navigation bar, etc.

You could certainly start your own media projection session using that API, and hide View 2 yourself as part of that. However, View 2 would be hidden from the user and the screen recording. There is nothing in the Android SDK that supports showing the user one thing but having the media projection ignore certain items.

Comment: can you plz explain this bit likely with some sample reference ,"You could certainly start your own media projection session using that API, and hide View 2 yourself as part of that." 
As I want to project/record only the fragment View of an activity.

Comment: @MuahmmadTayyib: You can call `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` on a `View` to cause it to no longer render on the screen. Then, it will not be recorded by a media projection.